# window elements not fit in window when mobile orientation changes from landscape to portrait?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a mobile application, initially when my phone is in landscape orientation and then changed to portrait, half of the window becomes invisible vertically. But the case is not with portrait to landscape. pls suggest some ideas to overcome this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you design with specifying dimensions on percentage of screen dimensions. so then all your content will be present even on varying screen resolutions as it sets all the elements dimensions as percent of the screen dimensions
    
 for more help visit [here](http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/advanced_web_design.asp)

Comment: I have desigined the screens with percent dimensions but still the prblm is coming

Comment: hey NejiHyuga, Now the problem is solved. I just forgot to mention one of the table's width in percent. your post just remind me of that when I croschecked my code.